# How to get non-matching characters?

Tags: c#, regex

In C# I have a the following Regex to test for valid usernames:

```
public const string ValidUserNamePattern = @"^(?=.{5,53}$)([\p{L}\w][.!_-]?)*$";
```

This should accept strings between 5 and 53 characters long, all characters including diacritics and the special signs '.', '!', '_', '-'.

If someone enters a name like `d'Agostini` or `van den Helde` we have invalid characters (spaces and '). How can I print only the **invalid** characters?

```
public const string ValidUserNamePattern = @"^(?=.{5,53}$)([\p{L}\w][.!_-]?)*$";

var validString = "TestUsrNèüäme";
var invalidString = "Te st|^us r";
var validUserNameRegEx = new Regex(OpManConstants.ValidUserNamePattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);

if (!validUserNameRegEx.IsMatch(invalidString))
{
    // How to get NOT MATCHING character or in other words
    // how to get all characters causing the Regex NOT to match?
}
```

Any idea how this can be done in C#?

Comment: Write a regex which matches if any of those characters appear in the string?

Comment: Do you mean first doing a check like this? https://regex101.com/r/YA851C/1

Comment: If I well understand you, correct characters are `[\p{L}\w]` and `[.!_-]`. You may create a regex that match the pattern `([^\p{L}\w.!_-])` and print all matches. I didn't tested it for now, this is why I comment.

Comment: `[\p{L}\w]` = `\w`. To do what you want you may use `Regex.Matches(s, @"[^\w.!_-]").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in comment, a solution is to find any character that does NOT match a valid character.
Your "correct character regex" is `[\p{L}\w.!_-]`, so your "incorrect character regex" would be `[^\p{L}\w.!_-]`.

```
protected const string ValidUserNameCharacters = @"\p{L}\w.!_-";

public const string ValidUserNamePattern = @"^(?=.{5,53}$)([" + ValidUserNameCharacters + @"]?)*$";
public const string InvalidUserNamePattern = @"([^" + ValidUserNameCharacters + "])";

var invalidString = "Te st|^us r";
var validUserNameRegEx = new Regex(OpManConstants.ValidUserNamePattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
var invalidUserNameRegEx = new Regex(OpManConstants.InvalidUserNamePattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);

if (!validUserNameRegEx.IsMatch(invalidString))
{
    var matches = invalidUserNameRegEx.Matches(invalidString);
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var match in matches.Cast<Match>())
    {
        builder.AppendLine("'" + match.Groups[0] + "' at char " + (match.Index + 1));
    }

    Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
}
```

Output is:

```
' ' at char 3  
'|' at char 6  
'^' at char 7  
' ' at char 10
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is first check / match if the string contains invalid characters using a negated character class and using `\p{L}` and add the characters `.!_-` that you would allow.

```
[^\p{L}.!_-]
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5e%5cp%7bL%7d.!_-%5d&i=d%27Agostini%0d%0avan+den+Heldecaf%c3%a9%2c+clich%c3%a9%0d%0aTestUsrN%c3%a8%c3%bc%c3%a4me%0d%0aTe+st%7c%5eus+r) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/wDAPhP)